# Why cant I grab attribute value of this node

Tags: c#, xml

This is the code that im trying with:

```
 var items = xdoc.Descendants("item")
                    .Select(item => new
                    {
                        MyImage = (string)item.Elements("enclosure")
                       .Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value)
                       .SingleOrDefault()
                    })
                    .ToList();
```

Here is how it looks in the xml file:

```
<item>
<enclosure url="http://ep00.epimg.net/politica/imagenes/2013/06/22/actualidad/1371899226_298900_1371917547_miniatura_normal.jpg" length="6409" type="image/jpeg" />
</item>
```

All I want to do is to grab the url

Any kind of help is appreciated

Comment: Why use an anonymous object for one string?

Comment: There is more, But I didnt add them to it, its just an example

Comment: Work with your class mate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17253954/stream-online-videos-using-rss-xml-tag-of-enclosure-in-windows-phone-7

Comment: @I4V Nice conclusion but thats not same question or same problem..

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
MyImage = (string)item.Elements("enclosure")
.Select(i => i.Attribute("url").Value)
                       .SingleOrDefault()
```

to

```
MyImage = (string)item.Element("enclosure").Attribute("url").Value
```

If you don't want to have to check for null's, you can try [these XML extensions](https://github.com/ChuckSavage/XmlLib/blob/master/XElementExtensions.cs) and write it like:

```
MyImage = item.Get("enclosure/url", "");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not that hard:

```
var result = xdoc.Descendants("item").Select(n =>
    n.Element("enclosure").Attribute("enclosure").Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the namespaces are involved, then `.Elements(name)` won't match if the namespace is not included. To test if this is the case, try replacing instances of `.Elements(name)` with `.Elements().Where(e => e.Name.LocalName == name)`.